# Get total Hours and minutes between two HH24:MI values

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the total working hour count between time in and time out.

let say time in = 09:00 a.m.

and time out = 17:30 p.m.

Then the query should return 8:30 i.e. 8 hours and 30 minutes.

I've tried the following :

```
 select (to_date('1730','HH24:MI') + to_date('0900','HH24:MI'))
 from olphrm.emp_attendance where emp_code=123 and time='05-DEC-16'
```

but it's throwing the following exeption:

> ORA-00975: date + date not allowed 00975. 00000 -  "date + date not
>   allowed"

How can I do this?

Kindly Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extract function:

```
SQL> select EXTRACT (HOUR FROM to_timestamp('17:30', 'hh24:mi') - to_timestamp('09:00', 'hh24:mi')) AS HR,
      2         EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM to_timestamp('17:30', 'hh24:mi') - to_timestamp('09:00', 'hh24:mi')) AS MN
      3   from dual;
```

Output

```
        HR         MN
---------- ----------
         8         30
```

Comment: I want the exact output  as 08:30

Comment: @AlinaAnjum - Its really not that difficult to concatenate two fields via `||` operator.

Comment: ok thanks. I've done it select EXTRACT (HOUR FROM to_timestamp('17:30', 'hh24:mi') - to_timestamp('09:00', 'hh24:mi')) || ':' || 
               EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM to_timestamp('17:30', 'hh24:mi') - to_timestamp('09:00', 'hh24:mi')) AS MN
         from dual

Comment: Agree with @SudiptaMondal, learn how to concatenate two column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it via `TIMESTAMP`

```
select 
     to_timestamp('17:30', 'hh24:mi') 
     - 
     to_timestamp('09:00', 'hh24:mi') 
 from dual;
```

It will return -

```
+00 08:30:00.000000
```

If you need specifics, you can extract like -

```
WITH data AS
    (SELECT to_timestamp('17:30', 'hh24:mi') - to_timestamp('09:00', 'hh24:mi') remaining
    FROM dual
    )
SELECT LPAD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM data.remaining),2,0) hours,
    LPAD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM data.remaining ), 2, 0) minutes
FROM data;
```

Comment: How would I get only 08:30?